# Apache mod_rewrite does not honor existing files with -f -and -d

Tags: apache, file, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect URLs for which no files or directories exists, with the aim to implement a cache. The configuration (in httpd.conf, not .htaccess) looks like this:

```
    <Directory /srv/xxx/htdocs>
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
            RewriteRule ^text/([0-9]+)$             /page.php?id_text=$1  [QSA]
            RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$  /page.php?url=$2 [QSA]
    </Directory>
```

But *all* filenames, even those of existing files, are run through the rewrite mill, as the rewrite log shows. And so I cannot use my file system cache as existing files are not honored.

What might be the cause?

Request http://ovula.xxx.net/Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden

The file is present:

```
sascha@v291:/srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs$ pwd
/srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs
sascha@v291:/srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs$ ls Ovula
Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
sascha@v291:/srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs$
```

From the rewrite log:

```
80.134.205.165 - - [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (2) init rewrite engine wit
h requested uri /Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
80.134.205.165 - - [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) applying pattern '^text
/([0-9]+)$' to uri '/Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden'
80.134.205.165 - - [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) applying pattern '^([^/
]+/)*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$' to uri '/Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden'
80.134.205.165 - - [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (1) pass through /Ovula/Kin
derwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/ovula.
xxx.net/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs/Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden -> Ovula/Kinderw
unsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/ovula.
xxx.net/htdocs/] applying pattern '^text/([0-9]+)$' to uri 'Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden'
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/ovula.
xxx.net/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/ovula.xxx.net/htdocs/Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden -> Ovula/Kinderw
unsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/ovula.
xxx.net/htdocs/] applying pattern '^([^/]+/)*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$' to uri 'Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden'
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/ovula.
xxx.net/htdocs/] rewrite 'Ovula/Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden' -> '/page.php?url=Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden'
80.134.205.165 - ovula [17/Aug/2011:08:49:00 +0200] [ovula.xxx.net/sid#2b0573ee35d8][rid#2b0574658288/initial] (3) split uri=/page.php?url=Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden -> uri=/page.php, args=url=Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden
```

Comment: Can you show a full example - the requested URL vs. the physical file name?

Comment: Which rule does not work as intended: this one `/page.php?id_text=` or the second one `/page.php?url=` ??

Comment: All rules apply - that is the problem. They should not apply to existing files.

Comment: Strange. `Kinderwunsch__ich_will_schwanger_werden` is not a symlink by any chance? Because those have their own switch, `-s`

Comment: You should repeat your conditions before the second rule

Comment: P.S. System administration questions, like configuring Apache, belong on http://serverfault.com. This isn't a programming quesiton.

Answer (score 2):

RewriteCond conditions apply to only one rule. If you want them to apply to all subsequent rules of the set, you may use something like that:

```
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     -d
        RewriteRule . - [L]

        RewriteRule ^text/([0-9]+)$             /page.php?id_text=$1  [QSA]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$  /page.php?url=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Hello LazyOne, after spending more than 10 minutes trying to register to mark this problem as solved I rather spent my time on other issues. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: The solution works but I think the interpretation is: If REQUEST_FILENAME is an existing file or directory then pass-through it and stop processing the rest of rewrite rules.